# PHP MYSQL How to find if a variable exists in mysql_fetch_assoc and its position in the array then set result as variables

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I am so stuck on something that I'm sure has a simple solution but it is defeating me and my basic PHP!

I have a MySQL db containing user entered tags (labels) for a collection of videos. I query the db to find the 5 most frequently appearing tags for the video.

```
 $sql_get_toptags=mysql_query("SELECT TagName,Count(TagName) AS TagFreq 
                                 FROM Tags 
                                 Where vidID='$vidid' 
                                 Group BY TagName 
                                 Order By Count(TagName) DESC limit 5",$db);
```

If I loop through the results, they are output to the browser no problem

```
 while($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_get_toptags)) {
   $tagname = $myrow[TagName];
   echo $tagname;
 }
```

What I want to do is find out if the tag the user has just entered is in that most frequent entered list and its position i.e 1.tagname I'd like the 1 and the tagname to be variables that I can reuse, in the example below $answer is the 1 $tagname is obviously the tagname.

This is what I have:

```
 $sql_get_toptags=mysql_query("SELECT TagName,Count(TagName) AS TagFreq 
                                 FROM Tags 
                                 Where vidID='$vidid' 
                                 Group BY TagName 
                                 Order By Count(TagName) DESC limit 5",$db);

  while($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_get_toptags)) {
      $tagname = $myrow[TagName];
      for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
         echo $i,$tagname;
         echo "<br>";
         if ($tag==$tagname){
           $TopTag=$tagname;
           $answer=$i;
        }
     }
  }
  if (($TopTag!='') && ($answer!='')){
     echo "your tag is no.".$answer;
  }
```

This doesn't work. here is an example of what it outputs:

1beard

2beard

3beard

4beard

5beard

1explosion

2explosion

3explosion

4explosion

5explosion

1rubbish

2rubbish

3rubbish

4rubbish

5rubbish

1volcano

2volcano

3volcano

4volcano

5volcano

1awesome

2awesome

3awesome

4awesome

5awesome

you're tag is no.5

I have tried what feels like a million combinations of loops I can't get what I want.

In my mind $tagname[] should be an array and the key the number in the brackets e.g tagname[2] it would be 3rd in the list. So if ($tag==$tagname[2]){ //echo "That tag is 3rd most popular"; } But $tagname is just one row and if I try creating an array in the while loop I just overwrite the last entry with each iteration.

I'd really appreciate any advice.

Output I want to see (i.e if $tag=explosion)

1beard
2explosion
3rubbish
4volcano
5awesome

you're tag is no.2

Comment: what's the expected ouput ?

Comment: added the expected output should be a list but the editor is insisting it be on one line.

Comment: as an aside, PHP functions that start with mysql_ have been deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. If you are in a position to do so, please consider updating your code to use the MySQLi or PDO extensions instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql_get_toptags=mysql_query("SELECT TagName,Count(TagName) AS TagFreq FROM GT_Tags Where VidID='$vidid' Group BY TagName Order By Count(TagName) DESC limit 5",$db);

while($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_get_toptags)) {
    $tagnames[] = $myrow['TagName'];
}
foreach($tagnames as $key=>$name){
    echo ($key+1)." ".$name;
    $reversed[$name]=$key+1;
}

if(isset($reversed[$tag])) {
    echo "Your tag is no. ".$reversed[$tag];
} else {
    echo "Your tag is not in the top 5";    
}
```

You could also use array_flip to swap the keys and array values.

Comment: Thank you, it's closer, but all that's output is "Your tag is no."

Comment: hold on, sorry I refreshed and the answer has changed.

Comment: I get this 0 beard1 explosion2 rubbish3 volcano4 awesomeYour tag is no. Which is even closer, but still no number

Comment: I have tried the following code and it works: $tag="two"; 
 $tagnames=array("one","two","three");
 
 foreach($tagnames as $key=>$name){
  echo ($key+1)." ".$name;
  $reversed[$name]=$key+1;
 }
 
 
 if(isset($reversed[$tag])) {
      echo "Your tag is no. ".$reversed[$tag];
 } else {
     echo "Your tag is not in the top 5"; 
 }

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql_get_toptags=mysql_query("SELECT TagName,Count(TagName) AS TagFreq FROM GT_Tags Where VidID='$vidid' Group BY TagName Order By Count(TagName) DESC limit 5",$db);
$tagNames = array();

while($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_get_toptags)) {
  $tagNames[] = $myrow['TagName'];
}

$tagNo = array_search($tag, $tagNames);
if($tagNo) {
  echo "Your tag is no. " . $tagNo;
} else {
      echo "Your tag is not in the top 5";    
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I get  this error:   "array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in" I don't think I'm getting an array I've had this problem $tagnames is always a string.

Comment: sorry I keep hitting return and posting comment instead of getting a new line. My brainhurts!!!

Comment: Now all I get is "Your tag is not in the top 5" even for tags I know are in the top 5

Comment: I made a typo in $tagNames. please update your code to see if it works now

Comment: I get this error again "array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in" Thank you for your help but karmafunk has solved it!